# cant update laravel 5.4 to 5.8

Tags: laravel

Laravel/framework v5.8.12 requires PHP ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.

But my PHP version in wamp is 7.2.18

[image]

Comment: In wampp you can use multiple php version. i think you are in version 5.6 when you are trying to upgrade.

Comment: seems you are using windows so from your terminal check your PHP version it should be 5.8.12

Comment: you need to point latest version of PHP i.e 7.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using windows so from your terminal check your PHP version it should be 5.8.12

As you are using windows pc please following instructions --

- Right-click on My Computer and select properties or access following
  the path.

  `Control Panel\System and Security\System`
- In that window on the left side, you will see

  `Advanced system settings`
- Clicking on  `Advanced system settings` will open a new window called `System Properties`.
- In that new window, you will see `Environment Variable` click there, then another new window will open.
- In that Environment Variables window, you will see two sections one
  is `User variables for User(user pc name)` and `System variables`
- Under the `System variables` section look for Path. Check below image

[image]

- Now click edit button which will open another window called Edit
  environment variable something like below image

[image]

- Now click add new and then in the input box you must paste the
  directory where php.ini exist.
- Now apply and save all the window
- Finally restart your pc.
- Now open your terminal and type `php -v` you will see your desired
  version. Now you can update your Laravel version.
- If it's not working but your version is ok then reinstall your
  composer and try again hope that will solve your issue

> NT: You can see in my PC I'm using multiple version of PHP but when I
>   type `php -v` in my terminal it shows 7.2.10. That because of my 7.2.10
>   having an upper position than 5.6 and you can change that. If you are having some kind of
>   information you can try these steps

Comment: can you explain what is not working provide us your errors. First of all tell me if you run php -v what does it say